# AWS CloudFormation Template for Orchestration of mutliple AWS Glue Jobs (combination of sequentially and parallel execution)

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless, aws-glue-workflow

I'm looking for help on CloudFormation Template for Glue Jobs orchestration for below scenario:

Suppose I have 6 AWS Glue Jobs, 3 jobs (Job1, Job2, Job3) should be executed parallel and remaining 3 jobs should be executed sequentially (Job3 executed before Job4 then Job4 executed before Job5, then Job5 executed before Job6). If any job failure, send Workflow "Failure" notification along with the failed Glue Jobname.

---

```
Job1 
Job2 
job3 --->job4--->job5-->job6
```

---

Comment: Ok, but what is your issue? Where is your current template and why it does not work? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a StepFunctions using `AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine` resource and define additionally `AWS::Events::Rule` for following events:

```
            EventPattern:
                source:
                    - "aws.states"
                detail-type:
                    - "Step Functions Execution Status Change"
                detail:
                    status:
                        - "FAILED"
                        - "TIMED_OUT"
```

Here is a sample single job execution stage in step functions:

```
                    Run Job 3:
                        Type: "Task"
                        Resource: "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync"
                        Parameters:
                            JobName: "GlueJob1Name"
                        Next: "Run Job 4"
```

You will have to enclose three parallel jobs within `Parallel` task type.

Comment: Rafal.... I'm very new to this CloudFormation, I don't have  experience in DevOps. If you don't mind, can you please share whole CloudFormation template for my scenario.                                                                *********************Thanks in advance for your reply **************************